# How do I activate a css style only when that area* of a div goes underneath another div? Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, canvas

Okay so lets say I have div1 & div2 in php.
Lets say div1 is 10px by 10px.

lets say div2 is 123px by 123px. (may contain image or videos)

When div2 goes directly underneath div 1 (while scrolling down). then the area that div1 covers on div2, turns blue or follows other css styling and only that area, not the whole of div2 gets changed. Apologize for not making sense.

See my illustrations below to get a better understanding.

[image]

```
<html>

   <head>

     <div id="div1">

     <div id="div2">

   </head>

<html>
```

Hope Everything made sense. Let's find a solution!

I have tried many solutions, but none that actually work.

Please post full code or a link to where I can test your demo.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. If you have an issue solving this yourself we're happy to help but please at least **attempt** to do this for yourself.

Comment: Are you sure you have divs in PHP?

Comment: I have attempted this myself yes, but I have no way forward from there. I've tried altertive methods, they don't provide what I need. So this is as clear as I can put it. If I had to prodive a code for this. It would be just simply div1 and div2. All I've tried is when the div1 reaches a certain part of the page, it changes color. Obviously that's not what I want. Im not looking for a code, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) should be good starting points.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Would you be able to provide a more specific solution then or perhaps a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use javascript (or bether JQuery) for this.

If you use JQuery, you can use the scroll event. If you are scrolling, do a check if it hits the other div.
https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Checking the positions of the divs is possible with offset/position.
http://api.jquery.com/offset/
https://api.jquery.com/position/

If you want to change the background, you give the div a background color that is pink. If it hits then you can add an additional background-image that has a specific background-position (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp xpos ypos).

I don't have tried it yet, but I guess it is possible that way.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a rough demonstration of the combination that you proposed exactly? how would you go about it?